# Do I need to move my Forge App to "Production", and if so, how? [autodesk-forge]

Tags: oauth-2.0, autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I have a Forge App (which, of course, is nothing more than a clientID/secret for establishing an OAuth connection). I saw a reference to "production", but couldn't find any info on how to promote it or get the production clientID/secret. Does this exist, and if so, how do I do it? Or is my app automatically in production?

When I did the exact same thing (OAuth App) with Procore, they had a very clear distinction between the initial "sandbox" environment that you used for dev & testing; and once you were ready, you made a request to promote the app to production and received your prod clientID/secret. Forge is not so obvious, but maybe I am expecting something that simply doesn't exist here.

Also, is it possible to list more than one callback url, and if so how? I need current up-to-date info on this, not answers from months or years ago. (I have seen old answers that mention a wildcard [*] but also users say that it doesn't work; and even that doesn't work for my urls, which are not identical in structure.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Forge apps do not differentiate the environment. You can create multiple apps, one for each environment. The API and features are the same. That app connects to BIM360/ACC, in which case we would recommend having 1 account for testing/validation/sandbox and, later, you connect to multiple customer accounts.
2. As of today, we do not support multiple callback URLs, but we're working on this feature.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that is very helpful. I am having a completely different now, I am trying to follow the upload files tutorial but there is a broken link: (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/document-management/upload-document/#step-6-upload-the-file-to-the-storage-object) points to https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-PUT but that is not a valid page. Any idea what the correct page is?

Comment: it should be https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-PUT/